# Simplest way to identify an Interface Builder element in code

Tags: xcode, xcode4, interface-builder

I am building a UI in Interface Builder and am looking for the simplest (least code) way to identify an element from code.

I'd like to avoid using outlets because frankly I detest visual programming and don't want to pollute my class space with countless outlet properties. Is there some unique string identifier I can assign to static elements that I can either reference directly or easily look up from code?

Ideally I just want to look up an object by its id like I can do in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('myIdentifier');
```

Comment: Outlets are the way to go. If you don't want the properties to be ~public~, declare them in a category in the `.m` file, for example: https://gist.github.com/rightfold/5924047.

Comment: @rightfold The strong typing of outlets is admittedly nice.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with rightfold that outlets are the best solution, but there is an answer that addresses your question directly: you can use the (integer) `tag` property of `UIView` (setting it either in IB or in code), and then you can fetch the view with the method `UIView -viewWithTag:`.

Successive calls to `-viewWithTag:` will iterate through the subviews that have the given tag. Because it's an integer, you'll probably want to use named constants for tag references in code, but unfortunately there's no way (that I am aware of) to use constants in that manner in IB.

The default value for the `tag` property is 0, so avoid using that as a semantically meaningful tag.

Comment: I looked at this and was surprised to discover that tag is actually just a numerical field, which seems like it would most certainly not be a good idea to rely on it for identifying elements.